# Why will not Grid CurrentRow.index include Grid Line Selection?

Tags: c#, datagridview

If you can, please help me!
I made a line in a grid list. The selection is made apparently. The problem is that this selection does not change the CurrentRow.index. The CurrentRow.Index value was 0 before the selection. There is still 0 left after the selection :-(. How can I solve the selection and the CurrentRow index add the same value as I did?

```
int row_again = 3;

DataGridView_CONNECT.Rows[row_again].Selected = true; 
int gridview_pointer = DataGridView_CONNECT.CurrentRow.Index;

//gridview_pointer = 0(?!)
```

Comment: Maybe SelectedRows would work? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please use the full name of controls `DataGridView` instead of "Grid". This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`dataGridView.Rows[index].Selected` actually does not selects a row. It sets a value indicating whether the row is selected.

If you would like to select a row programmatically, first, select a cell in that row:

```
DataGridView_CONNECT.CurrentCell = DataGridView_CONNECT.Rows[row_again].Cells[0];
```

Then you can update the information that row is selected and access to the `CurrentRow.Index`.

```
DataGridView_CONNECT.Rows[row_again].Selected = true;
int gridview_pointer = DataGridView_CONNECT.CurrentRow.Index;
```